# Some doubts on a classical example of Liouville Number

Tags: transcendental-numbers

> **Theorem (Liouville)** Given a real algebraic number $\alpha$ of degree $>1$, there is a positive constant $c=c(\alpha)$ s.t. for all rational numbers $p/q$ with $(p,q)=1,q>0$, we have
>   $$\lvert\alpha-p/q\rvert>\frac{c(\alpha)}{q^n}.$$

The author claims that, using this theorem, one can prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{10^{n!}}$ is transcendental, and he argues as follows.
Suppose not and call the sum $\alpha$.
Consider the partial sums $\frac{p_k}{q_k}=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{1}{10^{n!}}.$
Clearly $\lvert\alpha- \frac{p_k}{q_k}\rvert<\frac{c}{10^{(k+1)!}}$ for some constant $c>0$.

**If $\alpha$ were algebraic of degree $m$**, then by Liouville's Theorem, the left-hand side would be greater than $c(\alpha)/10^{k!m}$ and **for $k$ sufficiently large, this is a contradiction**.

**Questions:**
(1) when he claims "If $\alpha$ were algebraic of degree $m$", I guess he deals with $m\ge2$, so that he can apply Liouville's result. But what about the case $m=1$? In other words, why is $\alpha$ not rational?

(2) the proof ends with the phrase "for $k$ sufficiently large, this is a contradiction". Unfortunately, I don't where the contradiction is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $\alpha$ must be irrational, remember that rational numbers always have eventually periodic decimal (or indeed any base) expansions. But $\alpha$ clearly doesn't.

For question $2$, compare the denominators: for any $m$, when $k$ is sufficiently large we have $k!\cdot m<(k+1)!$, giving in turn $${1\over k!\cdot m}>{1\over (k+1)!}.$$ Now first imagine $c=c(\alpha)$, and then note that even if $c\not=c(\alpha)$ we still eventually get a contradiction as $k$ increases.

Comment: Of course, you are right. And I missed it... I upvoted your answer. I accept it if you can answer to question (2). Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: Once again, you are right! I'm very disappointed because of these very stupid questions...I spent some time on them unsuccessfully. Probably I'm too tired to study at the moment. Thank you very much for your patient.